# Qt 4.7 QColor constructor: possible bug?

Tags: qt, qimage

I am getting unexpected output from a piece of code that is simply accessing image coordinates, here's a snippet:

```
QImage image(imageFileNames[frameNumber]);
QRgb qrgb(image.pixel(493,114));
QColor testCol(qrgb);
```

Using the debugger to make sure I get the right image path I get something like `../seq/0001.png`, which is as expected. However, `testCol` has the values of:

```
[argb]
alpha 65535
blue 28013
green 24415
pad 0
red 59367
```

Instead of the expected value within the 255,255,255 range. Also, the value of qrb is 4293353325. The pixel coordinate is in image range (720x288 image) and image is in `.png` format (`QImage::Format_RGB32`).

I've also discovered that this problem seems to be global to the entire application and any new code that is written seems to inherit this behaviour.

Upon further experimentation, using the following code:

```
QRgb qrgb(image.pixel(1,1)); //again this is in range
int blue = qBlue(qrgb);
int red = qRed(qrgb);
int green = qGreen(qrgb);
QColor testCol(red,green,blue, 255);
```

`testColor` still has the wrong values. However, red, green and blue all show expected values. Seems like this is an issue with the `QColor` constructor? I'm not really too certain about what exactly is going on.

Any ideas what might be causing this behaviour? I am running Qt 4.7 on Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Use the "code" buttonto format code (indent by 4 spaces). Inline code is done by using backticks: `

Comment: Is cspec of your tesCol QColor::Rgb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QColor](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qcolor.html) is a union of different structures. Each structure is composed of 5 unsigned shorts.

QT uses internal bit shifting to store RGB values. So when you assign "1" as blue component it shifts it to make say 257. When you examine a QColor your debugger will show you 257 as blue component and you will get surprized !

On the other hand when you use the blue() method of QColor you should get 1 !

Don't use the debugger to examine the QColor use its getter and setter methods.

Here is an example taken from [QT code](http://cep.xor.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.2.2-browser/de/d05/qcolor_8cpp-source.html). You can see the bit shifting clearly.

```
QColor::QColor(QRgb color)
{
    cspec = Rgb;
    ct.argb.alpha = 0xffff;
    ct.argb.red   = qRed(color)   * 0x101;
    ct.argb.green = qGreen(color) * 0x101;
    ct.argb.blue  = qBlue(color)  * 0x101;
    ct.argb.pad   = 0;
}
```

Comment: Better late than never, this was definitely the cause of the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

In the description of the [`QColor`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcolor.html#details) class (in the Integer vs floating point Precision part) it is explains that color component are stored using 16-bit integer. So RGBA values are stored in the range of 0-65535. So maybe the code has evolved and now returned a 16-bit integer instead of a 8-bit.

I can't test now but the question is: Is the function result wrong or is the documentation wrong?

You should open an issue to point this to the Qt Dev Team.

Comment: The odd thing is that I've been using this same code for months now and the integer values returned have always been 8-bit. Those values DO correspond to the 16-bit equivalents of the image pixel values. It's all very strange.

Comment: Maybe a try in a dev version of Qt that has not been restore in the final version